# $ is not defined error in Selenium test

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, selenium, selenium-webdriver, capybara

I'm trying to test jQuery autocomplete in a Rails 3.2 app using Selenium. Following [this blog post](http://ruby-journal.com/how-to-do-jqueryui-autocomplete-with-capybara-2/) I've created a `fill_autocomplete` helper method that looks like this:

```
def fill_autocomplete(field, options = {})
  fill_in field, with: options[:with]

  page.execute_script %Q{ $('##{field}').trigger('focus') }
  page.execute_script %Q{ $('##{field}').trigger('keydown') }
end
```

When I run RSpec, I get this error:

```
Failure/Error: fill_autocomplete 'crop', with: 'm'
 Selenium::WebDriver::Error::JavascriptError:
   $ is not defined
```

The problem line is `page.execute_script %Q{ $('##{field}').trigger('focus') }`

---

**spec_helper.rb**

```
ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= 'test'
require File.expand_path("../../config/environment", __FILE__)
require 'rspec/rails'
require 'rspec/autorun'
require 'coveralls'
require 'simplecov'
require 'capybara'

include Warden::Test::Helpers

SimpleCov.configure do
  add_filter 'spec/'
end
Coveralls.wear!('rails')

Dir[Rails.root.join("spec/support/**/*.rb")].each {|f| require f}

RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.fixture_path = "#{::Rails.root}/spec/fixtures"

  config.use_transactional_fixtures = true

  config.infer_base_class_for_anonymous_controllers = false

  config.order = "random"

  config.include Devise::TestHelpers, :type => :controller
  config.extend ControllerMacros, :type => :controller
end
```

**dev/test group of Gemfile**

```
group :development, :test do
  gem 'haml-rails'                     
  gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 2.12.1'       
  gem 'webrat'                         
  gem 'capybara', '~> 2.4.1'            
  gem 'selenium-webdriver', '~> 2.42.0' 
  gem 'factory_girl_rails', '~> 4.0'    
  gem 'coveralls', require: false      
end
```

---

I've tried downgrading RSpec, Capybara, and Selenium-Webdriver. I've tried using Capybara-Webkit instead of Selenium. All to no avail.

I've been working under the assumption that jQuery autocomplete hooks into the 'keydown' event and that Capybara's `fill_in` doesn't trigger this event on it's own. Is this correct?

Any solution or workaround is welcome. Thanks!

Comment: Sounds to me like you've not got jQuery mapped to `$`. So to prove it, do a test: run your automated test **up until** it attempts to trigger the script. Once there, stop the test. Now, open up Chrome/Firefox's dev tools, and **run the same script manually**. You should, in theory, get the same error. If so, it's merely because `$` is not always going to be mapped to `jQuery` (and it's very very wrong to always assume that).

Comment: Thanks to your debugging advice I could figure out that it was an error in the JS that was happening before JQuery was defined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to Arran's advice I realized that an error elsewhere in the JS was happening before JQuery could be defined.